# Loaded the nib but didn't get a UITableView Exception

Tags: ios, uitableview, nib, ecslidingviewcontroller

I'm trying to load a `uitableview` using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController/) methods.

When I call this code:

```
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone"
                                              bundle:nil];
UITableViewController* page = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tableViewPage"];

CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = page;
self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
[self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
```

while "tableViewPage" is a tableView Controller, not a view with a table.  It gives me:

> [UITableViewController loadView] loaded the
>   "Bzc-w8-vsI-view-gnu-XH-Eb0" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

I tried to made a method like `topViewController` just for `uitableviewcontroller` instead of `uiviewcontroller` ... but I failed. What did I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's trying to tell you that you have a `UITableViewController` in your storyboard but the top-level view associated with that controller is not a `UITableView`.

Comment: @Julia as far as i know you must have a `UITableView` as the top-level view (if you are subclassing your class with `UITableViewCntroller`. If you want to use a UIView as the top level you should subclass with `UIViewController` and add `<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>` to your subclassed `.h` file

Comment: so can you tell me what do you using swift @SaadMasood