# Swift (XCode) - sigabrt error

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

I'm new to xcode and Swift.

When I finished my application, I got error "SIGABRT". I've heard that it's pretty common, but all solutions that I've found on the Internet don't work. I've also heard that my code is correct, but there is problem in storyboard.

```
var NamesOfExercises = [
    ["name":"example1"],
    ["name":"example2"],
    ["name":"kexample3"]]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return NamesOfExercises.count
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mycell") as! ExercisesTableViewCell
    cell.nameLabel.text = NamesOfExercises[indexPath.item] ["name"]
    return cell
}
```

Screens:

[image: http://imgur.com/ZeA8fJQ]

[image: http://imgur.com/sDlTQCb]

`

---

Comment: Your code is fine and the error mentioning a a probelm while loading the nib. Could you upload the project and send the link?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028129/how-to-fix-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview-error or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924146/loaded-the-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview-exception. Search for ["nib but didn't get a UITableView"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22nib%20but%20didn%27t%20get%20a%20UITableView%22).

Comment: @Ismail here You go http://speedy.sh/zaXRq/WinterAtHOme-v2-sigabrt.zip

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller is defined to be a table view controller (`UITableViewController`), but the top level object in your NIB is not a table view (you probably have a standard view, possibly even one with a table view as a subview).

You can get a very similar error with storyboards if scene that you dropped onto your storyboard was a standard `UIViewController` object rather than a `UITableViewController` object.

If you're using NIB, make sure that the top level object is a table view. And make sure to hook up the outlet, delegate, and datasource of your table view to the NIB's file owner.

Comment: Where and how to change class of nib?

Comment: If you're using NIBs, you just need to make sure that the top-level object is a table view. If you're using storyboards, you need to make sure that you dragged the "table view controller" object onto the storyboard rather than a standard "view controller" for which you then added a table view to that scene (or, if you needed this design because there were other controls on the view controller, change the base class class for your view controller to `UIViewController`, create an `IBOutlet` for the table view, and then hook up the outlets).

Comment: @T.Chechelski - If you're still having problems, you should edit the question, showing us how you instantiated the view controller and describe how you set up your NIB/storyboard, because the problem may rest there, rather than in the table view controller's code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the view of the loaded nib file is a `UITableView` object

Comment: How to find nib file?

Comment: In Interface Builder

Comment: Im such a newbie D: I cant find it - its about class created by me or what? Sorry for my lack of knowledge

Comment: I didnt load any nib file. Ive loaded only few images and created new class

Comment: The associated view of an `UITableViewController` must be an `UITableView` instance otherwise you get that error.

Comment: http://imgur.com/m9bzs3s

Comment: I think that everything is set fine

Comment: The error message clearly says that the `UITableViewController` couldn't find a `UITableView` instance associated to its view property. Did you read all suggested links?